# ActiveX registered as Media Type Player fails under IFrame

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, iframe, activex, mime-types

I've written an ActiveX control that registers itself to be the player for a particular mime type (`application/pdf`) by following instructions [on this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751976(v=vs.85).aspx). The player works fine when you browse directly to content that matches the media type, but fails to load the control completely if the URL resides inside of an IFrame. The URL for the IFrame is the same for the file that was previously loading when browsed to directly.  **The control is signed with a valid code-signing cert.**

In other words, browsing to `http://localhost/test.pdf` works.

Browsing to `http://localhost/pdfframe.html` fails, and contains this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://localhost/test.pdf">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Specifically, I see the constructor on the control fire. I've implemented `IObjectSafety`, and I also see `SetInterfaceSafetyOptions()` fire, but the control goes silent after that. `Form_Load()` is never called.

Could this be my `IObjectSafety` implementation, or some other issue?

In IE, under Internet Options -> Programs -> Manage Addons, the addon is approved to run for  `*`.

I've declared `IObjectSafety` using:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComImport()]
[Guid("CB5BDC81-93C1-11cf-8F20-00805F2CD064")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IObjectSafety
{
    [PreserveSig()]
    int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, 
                 out int pdwEnabledOptions);

    [PreserveSig()]
    int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, 
                int dwEnabledOptions);
}
```

And implemented it my class with:

```
    int IObjectSafety.GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, 
            out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions)
    {
        ObjectSafetyOptions m_options = 
                ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | 
                ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
        pdwSupportedOptions = (int)m_options;
        pdwEnabledOptions = (int)m_options;
        return 0;
    }

    int IObjectSafety.SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, 
            int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Acrobat Reader has no problems with this, btw... but is registered as an [Active Document Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dssbex6h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Still don't have a solution for this, but looking.

Comment: Can you fire-up fiddler and tell me what the content-type header is in the GET response of that pdf file?